# Как вывести ссылки на след/пред страницу пагинации joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

в стандартной пагинации  joomla есть кнопки вперед/назад/вконец/вначало и собственно кнопки с номерами страниц. 
Как помимо основной пагинации дополнительно вывести кнопки вперед/назад? 
Другими словами как вывести ссылку "следующая страница" если такова есть?
Спасибо

Comment: http://jdevelop.info/articles/jtemplates/215-pagination-php-pereopredelenie-vyvoda-postranichnoj-navigatsii-joomla

Comment: @labris немного не то. По ссылке описано как переопределить внешний вид пагинации. Мне нужно же получить ссылку и вывести в шаблоне. К примеру так я сделал rel next / rel prev '$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$pagdata = $this->pagination->getData();
if($pagdata->next->link){
$doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->next->link, 'next');
}
if($pagdata->previous->link){
$doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->previous->link, 'prev');
}'  тогда ссылка с атрибутом добавяется в <head>...</head>  а мне нужно добавить ссылку прямо в body

Comment: Я не совсем понял. Нужно добавить кнопки "Вперед" и "Назад" к стандартной пагинации вперед/назад/вконец/вначало + номера страниц? Или определить ссылку на следующую/предыдущую страницу?

Comment: @labris в идеале мне нужно вывести ссылку в шаблоне на следующую страницу при постраничном разбиении. При достижении последней страницы ссылку "следующая" не показывать. Пагинация должна остаться. Нужна отдельная кнопка! Я думал вытянуть можно ссылку из пагинации, но не знаю как! Вообще подойдет любой способ который даст возможность добавит в шаблон ссылку на следующую страницу и скрыть ее если следующей страницы не существует. (аналогично кнопке "next" в пагинации).

Comment: В файле pagination.php - $html .= '<li class="pagination-next">' . $list['next']['data'] . '</li>'

Comment: @labris да я понял, у меня немного по-другому. Я так сказать "любитель" в php и не знаю как вызвать правильно ссылку в самом шаблоне. делаю вот так  `<?php 
 function pagination_list_render($list)
{
$currentPage = 1;
 $range = 1;
$html .= $list['next']['data']; 
 return $html;
}
   ?>` естетсвенно джумла ругается... :(

Comment: @labris Я так понимаю мне нужен аналогичный код `<?php if($this->params->get('catPagination')) echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>` только вместо getPagesLinks(); мне нужно "впихнуть" next

Comment: @labris  или может Вы знаете как упростить/изменить `$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$pagdata = $this->pagination->getData();
if($pagdata->next->link){
$doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->next->link, 'next');
}
if($pagdata->previous->link){
$doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->previous->link, 'prev');` только чтобы данный код можно было добавить в боди. Это было бы универсальное решение независимо от того какая пагинация в шаблоне. К сожалению мягко говоря не силен в php, поэтому прибег к помощи. Спасибо

Comment: @labris  Сделал вот так, осталось впихнуть это как то в ссылку `<?php 
$next_button =$pagdata->next->link;
$pagdata = $this->pagination->getData();
if($pagdata->next->link){
echo $next_button; }
?>`

Comment: @labris фух вроде сделал `<?php if ($next_button =$pagdata->next->link): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $next_button; ?>">_</a>
<?php endif; ?>` не скажете корректно ли это ?

Comment: Вполне нормально :)

Comment: @labris спасибо, вроде бы ерундовая вещь, а средняя глубина просмотров с 2-3 выросла до 5-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Add rel=prev/next
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$pagdata = $this->pagination->getData();
if($pagdata->next->link){
$doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->next->link, 'next');
}
if($pagdata->previous->link){
$doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->previous->link, 'prev');
}

?> 

// Add button next page
<?php if ($next_button =$pagdata->next->link): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $next_button; ?>">_</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```